# Is it possible to make a slick grid control auto-size its height to between a min-max range to fit the number of rows?

Tags: slickgrid

I'm creating a website where a grid might have few rows or it might have many.

When there are only a few rows a lot of space is wasted in the grid on empty space.

Ideally I would like to be able to set a minimum height and a maximum height and then have the slick grid auto-size itself within that range based on the number of rows.

I've had a search around and found that there's an option for making the grid auto-size to the number of rows but it's apparently incompatible with paging.

```
var gridOptions = { autoHeight:true };
```

[How to get slickgrid div to resize with size of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842504/how-to-get-slickgrid-div-to-resize-with-size-of-table)

It also seems you can't set a maximum height; it'll keep expanding until everything is displayed.

Does anyone have any solutions or suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to adjust the height of the surrounding DIV instead of resizing the grid. SlickGrid's height is calculated based on the height of the DIV it is initialized on. So theoretically, you could modify the height of DIV based on the amount of data you have and then manually initialize the grid.

Check this link for an example on explicit init of the grid:
http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-explicit-initialization.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response :) That's certainly an approach to investigate. I have a feeling that it won't play nice with resizing the grid when rows are added or deleted after initialisation though.

Comment: You could reinit the grid on add-new-row and delete. I understand this is a workaround, but the grid takes over properties from it's parent DIV - so I think this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I handle three different "height" cases:

1. Height grows dynamically and is constrained to some `maxHeight` based on # of *visible* rows
2. Height grows dynamically and is not constrained (page will scroll)
3. Height is fixed and static (and may show whitespace if only 1 row, for example)

Basically I use `autoHeight` for case #2, and for case #1 (but only for case #1 if count of rows is less than the desired number of visible rows). For case #1 I use `rowHeight` and my own invention, `maxVisibleRows` to let developer say "this table will grow up to 5 rows before it starts scrolling, and the height of the scrollable area is equal to the sum of the heights of 5 rows." For case #3 it's just a simple parent height constraint which is the default behavior for SlickGrid.

Sample code:

```
    var parentContainer = document.getElementById("slick_container");
    var uniqueRecordIdField = "id";
    var rows = [{id: 1, product: "Bells"}, {id: 2, product: "Whistles"}]; // data (array of rows)
    var maxVisibleRows = 3; // user can see 3 rows without scrolling

    var HeightOptions = { Static:0, Auto:1, Max:2 }; // "enum" for illustrative purposes

    var HeightOption = HeightOptions.Auto; // dev would set this somehow
    var options = { ... }; // slick grid options object
    var parentHeight = "";
    switch (HeightOption)
    {
      case HeightOptions.Static:

        parentHeight = "400px;" // (hardcoded default/example; probably should allow override)
        options.autoHeight = false; // do not use slickgrid auto height
        break;

      case HeightOptions.Max:

        // use # of rows to determine whether table should be scrollable
        if (maxVisibleRows > 0 && rows.length > maxVisibleRows)
        {
           var arbitraryHeightPadding = 14; // style hack for viewport
           // constrain height to only show X rows
           parentHeight = ((options.rowHeight * maxVisibleRows) + arbitraryHeightPadding) + "px";
           options.autoHeight = false; // do not use slickgrid auto height
        }
        else
        {
          // use slickgrid autoHeight to allow height to shrink / grow
          parentHeight = "";
          options.autoHeight = true;
        }
        break;

      case HeightOptions.Auto:
      default:

        parentHeight = ""; // or could use 'inherit' or 'auto' or whatever probably
        options.autoHeight = true; // use slickgrid auto height to grow indefinitely
        break;
    }

    // set height of slick grid parent (container)    
    parentContainer.style.height = parentHeight;

   // do normal slick grid rendering stuff... 
   DataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args)
   {
      Grid.updateRowCount();
      Grid.render();
   });    
   DataView.beginUpdate();
   DataView.setItems(rows, uniqueRecordIdField);
   DataView.endUpdate();
```

Comment: Note that this does not cover cases for `minHeight` but to achieve this you could extend the example similarly to the `maxHeight` method. Though in practice with my customers I have never had this request (never had somebody say, "I want a table that is at least 5 rows tall (even if table has less than 5 rows), but becomes scrollable at 10 rows tall"). Usually it's either fixed height (to get benefits of floating header that is visible regardless of scroll position), or grow up to a max rows before scrolling.